# foldl operation in SML

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj, fold, ml

I perform the following `foldl` operation

```
foldl (fn (acc,y) => if acc>y then acc else y+1) 0 [1,3]
```

So, I expect this to produce me an result of `4` but it produces an output of `3`. What am I missing ?

My trace is something like this:

```
acc: 0   y: 1
acc: 2   y: 3
```

and since acc > y, i.e 2>3 it should go into the else branch and return 4 (3+1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accumulator is `foldl`'s first parameter's second parameter. So try this:

```
foldl (fn (y,acc) => if acc>y then acc else y+1) 0 [1,3]
```

See [here](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/list.html#SIG%3aLIST.foldl%3aVAL)

Answer (score 2):

Progression:

```
fn(0,1) => not(0>1) = 1+1 = 2: new acc 
fn(3,2) => is(3>2) = 3: new acc
fn([],3) => 3: final answer
```

foldl computes a new value immediately, foldr only begins returning a value once it has reached [].